# How to give ID to row dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am generated a row dynamically in this fiddle.I want to give ID to that row .And Display that on header can we give this.I want to give ID like this 1,2,3...

But there is a problem Is that That rows are nested So can we give ID to inner row also .IF there is an row inside first his ID 1_1, 1_2....If some element is inside 1_1.then it ID id 1_1_1....So on

Can we do this ?

```
function buildNav(nodes) {
    var result = '<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="stuff">';
    var i = 0, len = nodes.length;
    for(; i < len; i++) {


        result += "<div data-role='collapsible' data-content-theme='c'><h3>test</h3>"+content;
        if(nodes[i].testCaseList) {
            result += buildNav(nodes[i].testCaseList) + "</div>";
        }
        result += "</div>";
    }
    return result + "</div>";
}

$(function(){
  $('#test  ').html(buildNav(testData.testCaseList)).trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change the signature of the function? If so, you can pass the level to the function and prepend it to the id.

Comment: can to elaborate ? what type of sighnature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the value of the current level to your function and prepend it to the id.

```
function buildNav(nodes, level) {
    var result = '<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="' + level + '">';
    var i = 0, len = nodes.length;
    for(; i < len; i++) {
        var id = level + '_' + i;

        result += "<div data-role='collapsible' data-content-theme='c'><h3>test</h3>"+content;
        if(nodes[i].testCaseList) {
            result += buildNav(nodes[i].testCaseList, id) + "</div>";
        }
        result += "</div>";
    }
    return result + "</div>";
}

$(function(){
    $('#test  ').html(buildNav(testData.testCaseList, 0)).trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: where is your fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dn4XB/11/ It is fine. can header change to tc_1, tc_2,tc_3....inside if there is some thing tc_1_1,tc_1_2

Comment: You can pass whatever you want as the level name. So if you pass "tc" as level to the first call all your ids will start with tc instead of 0.

Comment: Answer is great can we change the header.Like tc_1,tc_2.If there is row inside tc_1 , then it become tc_1_1.If there is row inside tc_1_1_1

Comment: I have to add button when commandList array come with text of "command name"

Explain :
testCaseList have two object .On first object there is another testCaseList array in that object having commandList array on on that I need to add button on "command name".

on First object I have  testCaseList having 2 object .First have object no object in commandList.But first have commandList having 2 object so I need to add 2 buttons.

Comment: You should create another question for that and explain the problem thoroughly. I am sure it will be answered by someone if not by me.

Comment: please look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892614/how-to-add-button-using-json-parsing-in-jquerry